# Is the icons in Applications menu hardcoded?

Tags: applications, icons, horus

It has been awhile and now I'm back on elementary OS. I think the last time I tried it was release 5.0

My question is: have the icons in Applications menu been hardcoded in Horus? I'm asking because no matter what I do I can't change them.

[image]

best regards
Storm